# norm of space($V=H_{0}^{1}(U)\cap H^{2}(U)$)

Tags: sobolev-spaces

hi  in the space  $V=H_{0}^{1}(U)\cap H^{2}(U)$ what norm i should consider ? i think its the $H2$ norm no?U is bounded regular open of $R^{n}$
thanks